# Issue integrating Action Delegate, Extensions, and Anonymous Type together

Tags: c#, delegates, extension-methods, anonymous-types, func

So i was playing with Extensions, Action and Func in C# in trying to mimic the way Ruby handles Iteration on collections. The idea is that objects (that are enumerable) handle their own iterations. I got success with Extensions and delegates alone and I have code below working as expected;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Student{ 
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static class Extensions {
    //for when you only need some operations on the items in the collection
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action){

        foreach(var item in items){
            action(item);           
        }
    }

    //for when you want to return a modified collection
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T,T> action){

        foreach(var item in items){
            yield return action(item);          
        }
    }

} 


public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
            new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 12 },
            new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Moin", Age = 13 },
            new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill", Age =24 },
            new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age =22 },
            new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron"  } 
        };

        var selectResult = studentList.Select(s => s.StudentName);


        selectResult.ForEach(name => Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", name));

        int i = 1;
        selectResult.ForEach(name => string.Format("Name {0}: {1}", i++, name)).ForEach(formattedName => Console.WriteLine(formattedName));

    }
}
```

Then I decided to throw Anonymous types into the mix and edited the above code to become as below and that's where my problem is. I keep getting a run-time exception and can't seem to figure out the problem. Kindly help look through or just run it to see.

The error is;
Run-time exception (line 17): Attempt by method 'DynamicClass.CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, System.Object)' to access type '<>f__AnonymousType0`2' failed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Student{ 
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public static class Extensions {


    public static void ForEach<T,TInt>(this IEnumerable<dynamic> items, Action<T,TInt> action){

        foreach(var item in items){
            action(item.Name, item.Age);            
        }
    }

} 


public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
            new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 12 },
            new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Moin", Age = 13 },
            new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill", Age =24 },
            new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age =22 },
            new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron"  } 
        };

        var selectResult = from student in studentList
            select new {Name = student.StudentName, Age = student.Age};


        selectResult.ForEach((string name, int age) => Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Age: {1}", name, age));

    }
}
```

Here's a link to it on dotnet fiddle
https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZT7ZB4

Comment: This works just fine in Linqpad 4 and 5.  Seems to be an issue with dotnetfiddle. Can you reproduce the issue anywhere besides dotnetfiddle?

Comment: @DavidL actually I haven't tried anywhere else, I only use dotnetfiddle when I'm trying out snippets or concepts such as this. Now, that you have mentioned it, I will try running it on it.

Comment: Well, your code works fine on local machine

Comment: I'm voting to close this as something that cannot be reproduced.  This seems to be a dotnetfiddle only bug.

Comment: Okay, this is truly a dotnetfiddle only bug. Thanks